# bower install - fails in Jenkins - with ENOTFOUND error

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, npm, bower, bower-install

```
    {
  "name": "concur-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.8",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.8",
    "angular-route": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-touch": "1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.2",
    "lodash": "3.0.0",
    "restangular": "1.6.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.2.5",
    "ui-bootstrap": "2.5.0",
    "angular-spinner": "0.8.1",
    "spin": "1.1.6",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "meetingApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.2.0"
  }
}
```

The above is my bower.json file and i get the error in the console

```
bower restangular#1.6.1      ENOTFOUND Package restangular not found
```

I searched for the similar error and found few links saying the bower 1.8.x has similar errors but i do get the same in 1.7.9 as well.

Let me know if i am going wrong anywhere, i am searching for this since 4 days but still no-luck

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: can you do the same and get the success from command line? and please paste the log of the jenkins output.

Comment: Can you paste your command that you are running to install also?

Comment: npm install bower
bower install
npm install
grunt --force                   are the command i run in jenkins